# Enable Perforce in all IntelliJ windows

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce

For some reason, Perforce is working on one project window but not the other. Does anybody know what I have do to make intellij recognize that the current project uses perforce. I have checked the `Settings -> Version Control -> Perforce` settings. Settings are good, I was able to connect.

I am lost, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VCS -> Enable VCS Integration`

Note that the this option is not visible if VCS Integration is already enabled.